# Which OAuth protocol version does WebAccountManager use?

Tags: azure-active-directory

I'm trying to read a document about exposing OAuth permissions but it starts out by saying:

> Before you get started, you sould [sic] have a firm understanding of which version(s) of the OAuth protocol your permission should work with.

...and gives the options as

1. The MSA v1 OAuth 2.0 protocol
2. The AAD v1 OAuth 2.0 protocol
3. The converged v2.0 OAuth 2.0 protocol

However, the only criteria the documentation gives for figuring out which one you are using is based on the URL to which the client sends requests (e.g. https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenant/oauth2/authorize).

I don't know what URL our application uses for auth, and thus don't know what version it uses. Our UWP app uses the WebAuthenticationCoreManager class to handle authentication. We specify "https://login.microsoft.com" as the AccountProvider and "organizations" as the authority (to the WebAuthenticationCoreManager.FindAccountProviderAsync method). We don't obviously specify an endpoint or protocol version anywhere.

What version are we using?

Comment: What libraries are you using? MSAL? ADAL? You can solve your issue by quickly doing a trace of what endpoints your app is hitting. You should honestly become more familiar with your own code here.

Comment: Is the "WebAuthenticationCoreManager" class not the library I am using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to register an Azure AD v1.0 application in the [Azure portal](https://portal.azure.com).

[Here's](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-native-uwp-wam) an excellent code sample that integrates the Web Account Manager into a Windows Universal app.

Comment: As another commenter said, you can use a tool like Fiddler to watch the network traffic. When you see the request outbound from your app, take a look at the URL it's requesting which would show you the token service endpoint.

Comment: Thank for the answer and the suggestion. We already have the application registered and working, I just couldn't find in the WAM or Windows docs that specifically indicated which version of the AAD endpoint it used.