# How to get scope list from service for specifying with client authentication request

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

I have a UWP app that uses WebAccountManager for AAD authentication. I also have a service, hosted in Azure, used by the UWP app. That service uses the token the UWP app sends to get another on-behalf-of token (I think that's what it's called) to then call other service APIs as the user (e.g. Microsoft Graph and Outlook REST API). In other words, UWP app calls WebAuthenticationCoreManager.RequestTokenAsync to get a token, sends it to my service, my service calls AuthenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync to get an on-behalf-of token to use when calling the Outlook REST API, for example.

In the AAD registration for my service, the "Required Permissions" list all the services and permissions/API calls it might make on behalf of the user (E.g. "Microsoft Graph"-> "Have full access to user calendars")

When my UWP app creates the WebTokenRequest to pass into the RequestTokenAsync function, it currently passes an empty string as the value for "scope." What should it be passing for the scope parameter? Should it be passing the full and exact list of permissions that the service declares are required? If so, how do I get that permission list to the client? Just hard-code and update the list whenever the service required permissions list changes?

Comment: Did you ever figure out what to put for scope?

Answer (score 1):

In Azure Active Directory, there are two fundamentally different ways to specify the permissions your app requires when authenticating.

1. Static Consent
2. [Dynamic Consent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-compare#incremental-and-dynamic-consent)

Back in the Azure Active Directory V1 endpoint, you would set "Required Permissions" to other APIs when registering your client application. This is setting up **Static Consent**. These permissions are fixed, and when you trigger the user to consent to these permissions, the user has to consent to them all at once. Additionally, if at some point your app wants to add new permissions to other APIs, you will need to force the user to go through the full consent experience again, which may even require special logic on your application.

This is why in the V2 endpoint, Microsoft developed **Incremental and dynamic consent**.

> With the v2.0 endpoint, you can specify the permissions your app needs dynamically, at runtime, during regular usage of your app. To do so, you can specify the scopes your app needs at any given point in time by including them in the scope parameter of an authorization request.

Here, you can specify only the permissions your app needs to complete the flows it is trying to accomplish at that time. If you need more access, you can simply add it during your authentication experience, and it will prompt the user only for those new permissions.

Now let's return to your question. If you are using the V2 endpoint, you should be using Dynamic Consent, which means that the settings in "Required Permissions" do not really matter to you. You should be keeping the list of scopes your app requires in your app settings.

Some situations in the V2 endpoint still require Static Consent, like service to service calls with direct application permissions. For those situations you would pass the scope `<resource>/.default` as noted [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-protocols-oauth-client-creds#get-a-token). This might also work for delegated tokens, but it is better to just use Dynamic Consent.

Comment: How do I know what version of the endpoint that I am using? Based on your response, I suspect we are using 1.0 because we are using static consent. What should I specify as the "scope" parameter if using the V1 endpoint?  Note: I also asked about the version here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49056608/which-oauth-protocol-version-does-webaccountmanager-use

Comment: It depends on the token endpoint you call when getting an access token. `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/token` is for AAD V2. Note the `v2.0` in the url. Otherwise `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/token` is for V1. [Documentation for V1 here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-protocols-oauth-code). [Documentation for V2 here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-protocols-oauth-code).

Comment: Note there is no `scope` parameter when using the V1 endpoint.

Comment: From the answer to that other question, it appears that WAM uses the v1 endpoint. You say that there is no `scope` parameter when using the v1 endpoint, but there clearly is a `scope` parameter in the constructor for `WebTokenRequest`, it's the [second parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Security.Authentication.Web.Core.WebTokenRequest). Are you saying that it's just ignored and it does not matter what is put there?